# Помогите с переменными на javascript

Tags: html, java, javascript

Вообщем имеется кусок программы

```
$('#mchatMsgF').keyup(function(){
```

Как добавить дополнительную переменную *#message*?
Т.е мне надо, чтобы код работал как для *mchatMsgF* так и для *message* - одновременно!

Пробовал так:

```
$('#mchatMsgF #message').keyup(function(){
```

Но не работает, кто подскажет как это делается?

Comment: дела... *дополнительную **переменную** #message*... 

Вердикт ->> матчасть =)

Answer (score 2):

Это не переменная, а поиск элемента по id (xpath)

Попробуй так

```
$('#mchatMsgF,#message').keyup(function(){
```

Comment: а вообще все это есть тут: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Черт, как же я сразу не допер, тупо запятую поставить надо, спасибо :)

Comment: @Владислав Хромов, для спасибо есть галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: @Владислав Хромов, кто вам сказал, что надо __тупо__ поставить запятую? Не проще ли _тупо_ сперва почитать?